# Substituição de valores

Tags: javascript

Estou a receber um array na variavel "myObj" ([00, 12, 45, 34, 23, 34, 34, 34, 05, 42, 21, 11, 31]).
E precisava de colocar esse valor no series, ou seja substituir o array que lá está hardcoded.
Tipo: series = [myObj, ...]

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // Valor que tenho
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "api/api_get_fogo.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();

var dataSales = {
  labels: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
  series: [
    [00, 12, 45, 34, 23, 34, 34, 34, 05, 42, 21, 11, 31], // Onde quero substituir
    [00, 24, 36, 03, 34, 10, 15, 20, 48, 19, 49, 32, 02]
  ] 
};
```

Comment: Parece-me uma pergunta simples para alguém que saiba minimamente de javaScript, mas eu realmente não estou a conseguir :v

Comment: Não coloque código como imagem, ao invés disso coloque-o como texto formatando apropriadamente no editor da pergunta. Independentemente disso não é de todo claro o que você está a tentar trocar e onde.

Comment: Pergunta editada, espero que esteja mais perceptível...

Comment: Isso são funções assincronas, o código dentro do `if` é executado muito depois do `dataSales` ter sido executado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se percebi bem o problema, mas a instrução:

```
dataSales.series[0] = myObj;
```

não funciona?

Se se pretender acrescentar em vez de substituir pode também utilizar o push:

```
dataSales.series.push(myObj);
```

Comment: Não, pois o "myObj" é uma variável local...

Comment: Ah! Não tinha realmente percebido o problema :/

Sendo assim na função de callback do pedido pode colocar as instruçoes referidas anteriormente.

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // Valor que tenho
    dataSales.series[0] = myObj;
  }
};

Comment: Pois, eu já tinha tentado isso, no entanto nem me dá erro nem aparece o resultado pretendido :v

Comment: Já consegui, obrigado pela a ajuda!